# How to check certain bits of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523724/c-c-check-if-one-bit-is-set-in-i-e-int-variable)

e.g. if I had a integer and i wanted to check what the value of bits 20-25 were, or if i just wanted to check if one of the bits is 0 or 1, how would i do that?

Comment: I mean I want to check like e.g. 20-25 were bits 00011 so it would be 3

Comment: So maybe a function, int x = Bits2Val(y, 20, 25);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int bitsToInt(int value, int s, int e) {
    int mask = ((1 << (e - s + 1)) - 1) << s;
    return (value & mask) >> s;
}
```

bitsToInt(7, 2, 3) returns 1

thinking about it a bit more, if what you want is to stuff several values into one int you can be better off doing [bitfields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and have compiler worry about masks and shifts.

Comment: seems to work, i was just trying to write one with the info from wiki, mine would have been terrible compared to that simple code.

Comment: there might be some boundary issues (I haven't tested the code extensively), use with care.

Answer (score 7):

Use standard logic operations such as logical ANDs, ORs, XORs and combine that with bit shifts. This should give you some ideas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

You would use the bitwise-AND operator between the integer and a "mask" value, which ignores all the other bits.  So something like this:

```
const int BIT_4 = 0x8;

// ....

int val = /* ... */;
if ((val & BIT_4) != 0)
    ; // Bit 4 is ON!
else
    ; // Bit 4 is OFF
```

Comment: I would say `1<<3` instead of `0x8`.  (Also, starting from zero this is bit 3, not bit 4.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using bitwise AND operator.

```
int x = SOME_VALUE;

// check 20-25 bits
if ( x & 0x3F00000 ) {
  // any of bits on
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
uint32_t
get_bits_20_to_24(uint32_t i_)
{
  union {
    struct
    {
      uint32_t bits1 : 20;
      uint32_t bits2 : 5;
      uint32_t bits3 : 7;
    } s;
    uint32_t i;
  };

  i = i_;
  return s.bits2;
}
```