# a function to check if the nth bit is set in a byte

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want a simple C function which will return true if the n-th bit in a byte is set to`1`. Otherwise it will return false.

This is a critical function in terms of execution time, so I am thinking of the most optimal way to do that.

Comment: duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523724/c-c-check-if-one-bit-is-set-in-i-e-int-variable

Comment: That's not a dupe, it specifically asked about **non-bitshift** methods.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The following function can do what you need:

```
int isNthBitSet (unsigned char c, int n) {
    static unsigned char mask[] = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
    return ((c & mask[n]) != 0);
}
```

This assumes 8-bit bytes (not a given in C) and the zeroth bit being the highest order one. If those assumption are incorrect, it simply comes down to expanding and/or re-ordering the `mask` array.

No error checking is done since you cited speed as the most important consideration. Do *not* pass in an invalid `n`, that'll be undefined behaviour.

At insane optimisation level `-O3`, gcc gives us:

```
isNthBitSet:    pushl   %ebp
                movl    %esp, %ebp
                movl    12(%ebp), %eax
                movzbl  8(%ebp), %edx
                popl    %ebp
                testb   %dl, mask(%eax)
                setne   %al
                movzbl  %al, %eax
                ret
mask:           .byte   -128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
```

which is pretty small and efficient. And if you make it static and suggest inlining, or force it inline as a macro definition, you can even bypass the cost of a function call.

Just make sure you benchmark any solution you're given, including this one <sup>(a)</sup>. The number one mantra in optimisation is *"Measure, don't guess!"*

If you want to know how the bitwise operators work, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642). The simplified AND-only version is below.

The AND operation `&` will set a bit in the target only if both bits are set in the tewo sources. The relevant table is:

```
AND | 0 1
----+----
 0  | 0 0
 1  | 0 1
```

For a given `char` value, we use the single-bit bit masks to check if a bit is set. Let's say you have the value 13 and you want to see if the third-from-least-significant bit is set.

```
Decimal  Binary
  13     0000 1101
   4     0000 0100 (the bitmask for the third-from-least bit).
         =========
         0000 0100 (the result of the AND operation).
```

You can see that all the zero bits in the mask result in the equivalent result bits being zero. The single one bit in the mask will basically let the equivalent bit in the value flow through to the result. The result is then zero if the bit we're checking was zero, or non-zero if it was one.

That's where the expression in the `return` statement comes from. The values in the `mask` lookup table are all the single-bit masks:

```
Decimal  Binary
  128    1000 0000
   64    0100 0000
   32    0010 0000
   16    0001 0000
    8    0000 1000
    4    0000 0100
    2    0000 0010
    1    0000 0001
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> *I* know how good I am, but you don't :-)

Comment: Lookup table, yes!  But I'd expect bit 0 to be the least significant bit in the byte, and so would have reversed the order of `mask[]` intialized entries.

Comment: Not always, @hardmath, a lot of the comms standards fill their octets from the "left". Like you, I prefer thinking of b0 as the least significant.

Comment: -1, verbose and error-prone to write, learn about bit shifting.

Comment: @blueshift, you only write it _once,_ or zero times if you simply steal this code :-) And I know about bit shifting, I was probably doing it when you were still a suckling :-) Others had already posted the bitshift solution, I just offered a different approach.

Comment: A different approach that relies on you entering more code, a correct list of mask values and results in larger, likely slower, code. Especially since speed was a requirement, this answer is inferior and deserves my downvote!

Comment: @blueshift, that's your right, of course. I was simply explaining. And you _never_ assume something is faster or slower, you always check. I'd be more prone to listen to you if you had done so. Benchmarking this function on my machine at optimisation `-O0` (none) got through a million checks in four thousandths of a second, that's two hundred and fifty million times a second (although, granted, it's a grunty octo-core development box). If you need better than that then, by all means, choose a faster solution. Personally, I doubt it would be necessary except in the most extreme  cases.

Comment: You can safely omit the `!= 0` part in your return statement, since `c & mask[n]` by itself already yields the desired return value. If I'm not mistaken, this will save two of your machine instructions, `setne` and `movzbl`.

Comment: @Philip, sometimes I prefer to optimise for readability :-) I'd be surprised if that change would result in changes to the underlying assembly but, just checking, it does. The `testb/setne` is replaced with an `andb` - whether that's an improvement, I couldn't say off the top of my head but it probably is. I though gcc was smarter than that.

Comment: Based on Agner Fog's documents, I really don't expect a LUT to be any faster than shifting. On anything non-stone age, a shift by any offset is an order of magnitude faster than even an L1 hit, nevermind a miss.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I have a small doubt.what is the exact reason for declaring the array as static inside the function.What would the performance implication if the array is non-static?

Comment: @liv2hak, making it static gives it static storage duration. That means it's not created anew every time the function is called, instead it creates it once at program startup.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The bitshift is way faster and the code smaller. Using a LUT is good is the values inside can't be easily computed. And the `mask` array should be named `masks` because it stores the masks but is not a mask itself

Comment: @Jojolatino, until you've measured the performance on your target platform, the assertion that one way or another is faster is unknown. C runs on a huge variety of platforms. As I stated, any method you consider should be benchmarked. And properly benchmarked, not by relying on what may be incorrect accepted wisdom.

Answer (score 26):

Just check the value of `(1 << bit) & byte`. If it is nonzero, the bit is set.

Answer (score 12):

Let the number be `num`. Then:

```
return ((1 << n) & num);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
bool isSet(unsigned char b, unsigned char n) { return b & ( 1 << n); }
```

Comment: I understand `unsigned char` for the byte value, but `n`? That seems odd.

Comment: well n can't be bigger than a byte...   it doesn't really matter much

Comment: Since `unsigned char` does not constrain n to only valid values, I would argue it's a [small] "code smell" with regards to readability. Of course, that's debatable and I'll agree it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be

```
    bool isNthBitSet (unsigned char c, int n) {
      return (1 & (c >> n));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   unsigned int n,a;
   printf("enter value for n\n");
   scanf("%u",&n);
   pintf("enter value for a:\n");
   scanf("%u",&a);
   a= a|(((~((unsigned)0))>>(sizeof(int)*8-1))<<n);
   printf("%u\n",a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
        int data,bit;
        printf("enter data:");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        printf("enter bit position to test:");
        scanf("%d",&bit);
        data&(1<<bit)?printf("bit is set\n"):printf("bit is clear\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code-only-answer requires some explanation in order to make the added value more obvious, in comparisoin to other, older, upvoted and mostly better explained answers (not implying that all other answers are better explained...).