# Coding in Bits. or Structuring a Byte into several different values with respect to corresponding bits. or Bitwise coding or Bit Manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I would like to have single byte with multiple funtions.

I would like to split a Byte into 5 parts; that is first half byte or first four bits, with 0-15 different values.

Then the last half of the byte or last 4 bits must be separated, each bit (that is 5th, 6th, 7th, or 8th_bit) must have  value of 0 or 1.

For example: if I pass value something like this "0b 1111 1 1 1 1". It should configure to the funtion which is there in value 15 of first 4 bits(0-15) and the 5th_bit(0-1) must be set(1) or clear(0) to do certain funtion and 6th, 7th, and 8th_bit must also do similar thing like 5th bit

[Maybe if you look into the **image** you might get what I am trying to say. Please click the **link** to see the **image**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFSuo.png) I am not sure about title, I think the title fits my question. I would like to achieve this in C++. How to achieve this? How to do this? any examples?

Comment: Have you looked into basic bitwise operators? Everything you describe is just a matter of some bit masking and bit shifting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: Yes, I have already saw that, but I am asking how to implement what I am supposed to do? let me know what knowledge I am lacking or lagging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use bitmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591924/how-to-use-bitmask)

Comment: @Frebreeze that was for maniplating each bit like either 0 or 1. The link you provided will help me work with last 4 bits. But in my first 4 bits, it should have values 0 - 15. How to do that?

Comment: IMO it's easier to move the first 4 bits to be the last, that way you can get the value using only a mask instead of shifting 4 to the right. Rest of the values are gotten anyways by masking

Comment: Bitshifting is a excercise of logical comparisons typically. Get comfortable with AND, OR, XOR. Also be comfy then with binary notation and hex notation. If you want to target the leading nibble (upper 4 bits of a byte), consider a comparison like: int x = myByte & 0xF0. Or in binary notation. int x = myByte & 0b11110000.

Comment: #"EyalK" #"Frebreeze" I did not get the point what your trying to say. Could you both explain in detail or maybe with example.

Comment: See @Armin answer for a very nice breakdown of bit manipulation.

Comment: @Frebreeze Yes that was nice explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn a littel bit about boolean algebra. Most important are AND, OR and NOT operations. You can build anything with these 3 operations. There are other Operations which can also be used to come to any desired outcome, like NAND and NOR, and more. But anyway.

C++ has bitwise operators for AND `&` or OR `|` or NOT`~`. Please do not mix up with boolean logical operators `&&`. `||` and `!` that work on boolean expressions.

Let us look like that bitweise operators behave. In the following example we are always talking about one sinegle bit:

```
AND  Result      Or   Result     NOT  Result
a b    y         a b     y       a       y
---------        ----------      ---------- 
0 0    0         0 0     0       0       1 
0 1    0         0 1     1       1       0
1 0    0         1 0     1
1 1    1         1 1     1
```

No we need to understand, how we can set a bit and clear a bit. From the above table you can see that

- Something AND 0  --> is always 0. So, we can clear a bit with AND 0
- Something OR  1  --> is always 1. So, we can set a bit with OR 1
- Something AND 1  --> is always "Something". So, AND with 1 is a neutral operation
- Something OR  0  --> is always "Something". So, OR with 0 is a neutral operation

OK. Now we know how to set a bit or how to clear a bit. We can also do multiple bit sets or bit clearences. So, if we want to set the uppermost 4 bits in a byte, we can write

```
byte = byte | 0b11110000.
```

That will set the upper most 4 bits and not change the 4 lower most bits.

If we want to delete/reset/set-to-0 the bit number 0 and 1, then we can write:

```
byte = byte & 0b11111100.
```

If we want to know the value of several bits, we can "mask" them. We can create a binary value, with bits set on positions that we want to read. Example. We want to read the 3 lower most bits.

So,

```
value = byte & 0b00000111.
```

Should be clear now. . . .

We have also 2 additional important operations, and that is shifting. Since bits, depending on their position, have a different value, we need often to shift tehm to the correct position.

In your example, letS write the value 9 to the 4 upper most bits. What we need to do is:

1. Delete any old stuff that is possibly thaer with masking
2. Create value 9 and shift it to 4 positions to the right
3. Delete the 4 lower bits of the shifted values
4. OR the result over the target value

```
unsigned char value = 9;
value = value << 4;
value = value & 0b11110000;
Target = target | value;
```

Of course you can do all this in one statement.

Reading the 4 upper most values will be the reverse approach.

```
value = target & 0b11110000;
value = value >> 4;
value = value & 0b00001111;
```

by creating bit patterns ( a mask) you can influence all desired bits

Answer (score 0):

You have several way:

- manual way, Do the [bitwise operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) manually, something like:

  ```
  struct S
  {
  private:
      std::byte getPage() const { return (data & 0xF0) >> 4; }
      void setPage(std::byte value) { return data = (data & 0x0F) | ((value & 0x0F) << 4); }

      bool getCtrl1() const { return data & 0x08; } // 1 << 3
      bool getCtrl2() const { return data & 0x04; } // 1 << 2
      bool getCtrl3() const { return data & 0x02; } // 1 << 1
      bool getCtrl4() const { return data & 0x01; } // 1 << 0

      void setCtrl1(bool b) { data = (data & ~0x08) | (b ? 0x08 : 0x00); }
      void setCtrl2(bool b) { data = (data & ~0x04) | (b ? 0x04 : 0x00); }
      void setCtrl3(bool b) { data = (data & ~0x02) | (b ? 0x02 : 0x00); }
      void setCtrl4(bool b) { data = (data & ~0x01) | (b ? 0x01 : 0x00); }

  private:
      std::byte data;
  };
  ```
- use [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field):

  ```
  struct S
  {
       std::byte pages : 4;
       std::byte ctrl1 : 1;
       std::byte ctrl2 : 1;
       std::byte ctrl3 : 1;
       std::byte ctrl3 : 1;
  };
  ```

  (but no guaranty of order)

Comment: I have already tried your "use bitfield" method but that dose not helped me. Also, it didnt unterstand clearly how you doing "manual way". Could you please explain manual way?

Comment: Manual way do bit field manipulation see [Bitwise_logic_operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators).

Comment: Sure will look into it.