# How to get the nth bit of a given decimal number?

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to get the nth bit of a given number (starting from the **end** of the binary representation of the number (from 0)).

So for example let's say we have the decimal number 7 and want to get the 0th bit. So 7 is 11**1** in binary and the 0th bit is **1**.

Let's say we have 9 which is 1**0**01 in binary and want to get the second bit. It's **0**.

I have the following idea in my head: so for the first example we take 11**1** & 00**1** = 001, which *isn't zero*, so the answer is 1.

For the second example we take 1**0**01 & 0**1**00 = 0000, which *is* zero, so the answer is 0.

So basically we take *bitwise and* on the number and a number with all zeros but 1 in the position we're interested in.

Can this idea be realised efficiently with code in C++? I don't know how to write with code the number with all zeros except in the position we're interested in. Thanks!

Comment: _"I don't know how to write with code the number with all zeros except in the position we're interested in."_ Per the linked question, that's just `1u << n` where `n` is the position of interested.

Comment: Also potentially helpful: [How to set, clear, and toggle a single bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/11082165)

Comment: More direct duplicates: [C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/523724/11082165), [How to get nth bit values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27412032/11082165)

Comment: It was all @brian :)

Comment: @PaulSanders, nope, someone else replied as well, but they probably deleted their comment.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is:

```
int get_bit_n(int x, int n) {
    return (x >> n) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Should `x` be an `int` or an `unsigned int`? Think about overflow cases.

Comment: No matter. In the task description specified `binary representation of the number`. Signed/unsigned - is just math/view interpretation of the binary representation. If it is more comfortable for you, you can use 'unsigned x'.