# How to check each bit in 16 bit address in C

Tags: c, bitmap, bitwise-operators

I have a 16 bit address 0-15, I need to check at value of bit corresponding to their position in C

for example at 15 place i have 1, 14 has 0, and soo on!

|1|0|0|0|1|0|1|0|1|1|1|1|1|0|1|0|

I was thinking to create 16 new addresses with all zero and the position i am looking

Comment: I was thinking to create 16 new addresses with all zero and the position i am looking and then do then and operation but I don't like that approach.

Comment: Are you saying you want, essentially, a function that returns the bit value of a 16-bit integer at an arbitrary bit position 0-15?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523724/c-c-check-if-one-bit-is-set-in-i-e-int-variable)

Comment: nope its different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro similar to this:

```
#define CHECK_BIT(x, i) ( ((x) & (1 << (i)) != 0 ) )
```

`CHECK_BIT(x, i)` will return `true` if the i'th bit of `x` is one, false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
int bitAtPosition(int value, int position){

   return (value & (1 << position)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Well taken! Modified as suggested.