# Check specific bit of QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, bit, qbytearray

I have an 8 byte `QByteArray` and I need to check a specific bit in that array, but not the same bit every time. It could be any of the 64 bits that make up that 8 byte array. Performance is priority!

My current method first grabs a specific byte from that array, then gets a specific half-byte (or nibble), and then converts to another `QByteArray` with binary representation using `QByteArray::number(x, 2)`, and then finally I check the bit. This sucks and I want a better way.

I opted to load it into a `QBitArray` so I can quickly and easily retrieve a specific bit. I assumed its representation in memory is the same as a `QByteArray` or `quint64`, so conversion would be accepted, but conversion is not allowed.

How would I check if a specific bit (0 to 63) in a `QByteArray` is 1 or 0, quickly?

Comment: Please add your current code into the question. I'm wondering why you are not using bitwise operator to know the value of the bit. http://stackoverflow.com/a/523737/2266412

Comment: Because that accepts an `int` where I'm looking for raw `QByteArray` bit checking. I would first have to find the specific byte where the bit is located, convert to an int, and then use that method. Where the byte position and bit position would require logic to figure out. Performance is a concern so I'm wanting something more direct and quicker.

I explained my current code and I'm not looking to use any of it at all. It's messy so I don't think posting it would be of any benefit at all.

Comment: The "logic" you're talking about is trivial on modern CPUs. You really should head out to https://godbolt.org and see for yourself.

Comment: `unsigned long long bit=reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>array.constData() & (1<<bitToCheck);` where `bitToCheck` is 0-based

Comment: @PaulBentley That will work if all three of the assumptions you've made are correct: the order of bytes, the order of bits, and the size of `unsigned long long`. Your chance of being correct is roughly 1 in 4.

Comment: Well, an unsigned long long is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.  The order of bytes can be controlled by how mrg95 puts them into the array.  The only outstanding issue would be order of bits within the byte, however I've programmed a lot of systems and typically this follows bit 0 = 1, bit 1 = 2 etc.  You have a different experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QBitArray` wasn't designed to be convertible to anything else; its internal representation is indeed internal.

Alas, bit checking is rather easy. Modern architectures use barrel shifters, so shifting is cheap.

There are several possible bit-to-byte mappings. Let's cover all of them:

```
        byte 0     byte 1       byte n-1   byte n
LL - [01234567] [89ABCDEF] ...
LB - [76543210] [FEDCBA98] ...
BL -                       ... [89ABCDEF] [01234567]
BB -                       ... [FEDCBA98] [76543210]
```

Thus:

```
enum class BitMapping { LL, LB, BL, BB };

bool getBit1(const QByteArray & arr, int bit, BitMapping m) {
  Q_ASSERT(arr.size() >= 8);
  auto byte = (m == BitMapping::LL || m == BitMapping::LB) ? 
              bit/8 : (7 - bit/8);
  bit = (m == BitMapping::LB || m == BitMapping::BB) ?
        (bit%8) : (7 - (bit%8));
  return arr.at(byte) & (1<<bit);
}
```

If we assume that the platform has sensible support for 64-bit integers, we can leverage those:

```
bool getBit2(const QByteArray & arr, int bit, BitMapping m) {
   Q_ASSERT(arr.size() >= 8);
   auto value = *reinterpret_cast<const quint64 *>(arr.data());
   if (m == BitMapping::LL || m == BitMapping::BL)
      bit = (bit & 0x38) + 7 - (bit & 0x07); // reorder bits
   if ((Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_LITTLE_ENDIAN && (m == BitMapping::BL || m == BitMapping::BB)) ||
       (Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_BIG_ENDIAN && (m == BitMapping::LL || m == BitMapping::LB)))
      bit = (bit & 0x07) + 0x38 - (bit & 0x38); // reorder bytes
   return value & (1<<bit);
}
```

Any decent compiler will inline either implementation above when specialized, e.g.

```
bool getBit(const QByteArray & arr, int bit) {
  return getBit2(arr, bit, BitMapping::LB);
}
```

You can also specialize it by hand for the `LB` case:

```
bool getBit1(const QByteArray & arr, int bit) {
  Q_ASSERT(arr.size() >= 8);
  auto byte = bit/8;
  bit = bit%8;
  return arr.at(byte) & (1<<bit);
}

bool getBit2(const QByteArray & arr, int bit) {
   Q_ASSERT(arr.size() >= 8);
   auto value = *reinterpret_cast<const quint64 *>(arr.data());
   if (Q_BYTE_ORDER == Q_BIG_ENDIAN)
      bit = (bit & 0x07) + 0x38 - (bit & 0x38); // reorder bytes
   return value & (1<<bit);
}
```

Note that the `Q_BYTE_ORDER` check is a compile-time constant and incurs no runtime overhead.

`getBit1` and `getBit2` are portable to all platforms Qt runs on, and `getBit2` generates a little better code than `getBit1`. On x86-64, the bit twiddling code from `getBit2` amounts to 5 instructions:

```
mov    $0x1,%eax
shl    %cl,%eax
cltq   
test   %rax,(%rdi)
setne  %al
retq
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what LL, LB, etc stand for? Can you clarify?

Comment: They stand for the order of bits in the byte array. There are four possible orderings. They are graphically illustrated. What's unclear?

Comment: Well, for starters, what L and B stand for. I assume Little and Big, but I got confused when I noticed that the first 8 bits in LL and LB are not the same.

Comment: @mrg95 They are not the same because the second letter is not the same :) It doesn't matter what stands for what, treat those as arbitrary identifiers. You still must know which of the four bit orders are used when encoding the byte array, and you have to choose the correct one to extract the data. You can name those four mappings in whatever way works best for you. Instead off `LL,LB,BL,BB` you could have `Mapping1,Mapping2,Mapping3,Mapping4`.

Comment: Okay let's say that I want to use only LB, is there a streamlined way of doing this? This seems overcomplicated.

Comment: This needs to make sense to the human reader. The compiler is very good at figuring out how to simplify it :)

Comment: Lol yet I'm having a hard time making sense of it. I believe you, but just humor me. I'm wanting to use only LB, so is there a simple one liner I could implement to do just LB? (And yes I actually do want to only do LB. I'm reading from a data file and that is how the bits are ordered)

Answer (score 0):

I guess all you need to do is traverse through bits.

1) checks for bit you wanted

```
if(j+(i*CHAR_BIT) == (bit-1))
```

2) Skips non required bytes if the passed 'bit' doesn't fit in specific byte

```
(((i+1)*CHAR_BIT) < (bit-1))
```

3) Skips all further bytes if the current bit position is greater than passed bit.

```
((j+(i*CHAR_BIT)) > (bit-1))
```

Below is the full solution.

```
quint8 checkBit(QByteArray bytes, int bit) {
    quint8 result=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.count(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; ++j) {
            if(j+(i*CHAR_BIT) == (bit-1)) {
                result = (bytes.at(i) & (1 << (7-j))) ? 1 : 0;
                break;
            }
            else if(((i+1)*CHAR_BIT) < (bit-1) || ((j+(i*CHAR_BIT)) > (bit-1))) { // out of range skips
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Note: As the position starts from 0,  so when you pass bit ..  say 8 which is actually  8-1 = 7 :  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]