# Read 'N' bit from a byte

Tags: c, mplab

I need to read a specific bit from a byte. The value i want to test is 0 or 1.

```
unsigned char Buffer[0]=2; 
//or binary 0b00000010
```

How can i read n bit from buffer. If it's 0 or 1?
Example if 7 bit from byte is 0 or 1

Comment: To begin with, you want to create an array of *zero* elements, and store a value in it? That won't work very well.

Comment: `char Buffer[0] = 2;` is ill-formed. It assigns `2` to an array of length 0. (I believe, even arrays of 0 length are ill-formed.)

Comment: As for your problem, you can't really "read" bits. You can mask out the bits you want from a byte using [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Comment: In general, to test for individual bits, C has bitwise operators. Example: [SO: C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523737/7478597).

Comment: The `unsigned` doesn't make it better. ;-)

Comment: Please add your attempts with the suggested solutions to your question and show us what results you get.

Comment: @Scheff Yes, arrays of size `0` are illegal. Its one of the classic ways to cause a compile-time error intentionally.

Comment: And please show us an example that actually compiles.

Comment: I'm using xc8 compiler and pic18

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must define precisely how you count the bits:

- starting at `0` or `1`
- from least significant to most significant or the other way?

Assuming bit `0` is the least significant, you can get bit `7` with this expression:

```
int bit7 = ((unsigned char)Buffer[0] >> 7) & 1;
```

Here is a generic loop:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    putchar('0' + (((unsigned char)Buffer[0] >> i) & 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example i try this but it doesn't show that the number is 1.  int bit7 = ((unsigned char)Buffer[0] >> 7) & 1;
            if(bit7==1) //rest of code

Comment: @ddd Yes it does. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ddd Check with e.g.:  `#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    //           bit 7:        |          |           |           |          |
    //           binary:       0000 0000  1000 0000   0111 0000   1010 0000  0111 1001
    unsigned char buffer [] = {0x0,       0x80,       0x70,       0xa0,      0x79};
    for(size_t i = 0; sizeof(buffer) > i; ++i) {
        printf("%u   %i\n", buffer[i], ((unsigned char)buffer[i] >> 7) &1);
    }
}` . It does what you asked for, doesnt it?

Comment: @ddd I think you are numbering the `1` in your example `0b00000010` as bit 7, which is not a convention anyone will recognize. With this notation, one usually starts counting at 0 from right to left. And if you want to extract that bit, you do `((unsigned char)Buffer[0] >> 1) & 1`

Answer (score 2):

To check a bit if its 0 or 1, you can define a simple macro like:

```
#define BIT_ISSET(var, pos) (!!((var) & (1ULL<<(pos))))
```

and then use it in if-clauses.

Note the '**!!**' operator, to ensure that it returns 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: which will check the value of 7th bit.

```
unsigned char Buffer = 2; //Hope this is what you are looking for 

if (((Buffer >> 7) & 0x01) == 1 )
{
    printf(" Bit is 1 ");
} 
else
{
    printf(" Bit is 0 ");
}
```

Similar way if you need to check the value of nth bit, replace 7 in if condition with n.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you had to define your bit position in advance.

e.g.
Bit7 (MSB)
Bit0 (LSB)

Test for bit 7:

```
if (Buffer[0] & 0x80)
{
    //do action for bit 7 = 1
}
else
{
    // do action for bit7 = 0
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesnt returns me 1:(

Comment: Bit count 0 ...7

Comment: But I guess that is not the problem

Comment: I think ddd and Swordfish are both confused about the conventions for numbering bits. FYI numbering starts at zero from the _right_. The number 2 has bit 1 set, not bit 7. Bit 7 is equivalent to 128.

Comment: it seems i am counting down from 42. nevermind, i was talking bs ;)

Comment: @paddy No, not confused at all, just tired and heading for bed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this function to pass your char and N(number of bit).The function will invoke a bitwise AND filtering out the bit you need to check.

```
bool check_N_bit(char a_char , int N)
{
    if (N>8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if ((a_char&(0x01 << N-1)) > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using `pow(2 , N-1)` instead of `1<<N` ?

Comment: Yes, I don't shift something.I just initialize a char.I could also have 0x01 and shift it for N bytes, you are right just different approach.

Comment: Are you aware that a shift will be much much quicker? Less code, less time.

Comment: Yes indeed , I fixed it.Good catch!

Comment: You are off by 1 bit

Comment: I use N-1 because I assume that LSBit is bit number 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184264/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-tsakiroglou-fotis).

Answer (score 0):

Here a function to get a bit n from x

```
int getBit(unsigned int x, int n){
    return (x >> (n-1)) & 0x01;
}
```