# C++ use of enums with bit OR operator

Tags: c++, enums, bitwise-operators, bit

I can't find any resource online on how to use this method, which is quitely widely used in libraries.

What I'm referring to si something that looks like this:

```
someFun(Class::prop1 | Class::prop2 | Class::prop3, somethingelse);
```

now, I can undestand that this is based on enums/ints that are power of 2, so something like:

```
class Class{
public
     enum{prop1 = 1, prop2 = 2, prop3 = 4, prop4 = 8};
};
```

and then use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523737/12361700) to check if the n-th bit is 0 or 1, but are there ways to do it in a cleaner way?

If you wan you can use this as example:

```
class Class{
public:
     enum{prop1 = 1, prop2 = 2, prop3 = 4};
     void f(int i){
         if( ... ) ...
     }
};
```

I was thinking maybe using the `&`operator, like `if(i & Class::prop1) ...` but idk if it's the right way to do it

Comment: That's the way you use it, it's quite common in C programming. You could also use a `std::bitset` and pass enums with implicit values (0, 1, 2...). The thing is that the if will only evaluate to false if the result is 0, which in a bitwise AND operation that means that the only bit set (in the enum operand) is not set in the bitset.

Comment: `if(i & Class::prop1) ...` is correct. it will be true only if the bit of prop1 is 1 in i. Since prop1...propn are only one bit each this will work

Comment: @JorgeBellon can you please post an answer about `std::bitstet`?

Comment: @Tomer thank you for the confirmation, are there way to use this in some king of switch instead of a list of if statement?

Comment: @Berto99 No. Since there can be several bits set in i, a switch won't work. Switch statement can only jump to one label based on the number.

Comment: thank you both for your time, feel free to give an answer, I'll be more tahtn glad to accept it and upvote them

Comment: It does not work in a switch because you might have multiple flags set at one time. For example, `(prop1 | prop3) != prop1`, so `prop1` case would not match in this case. You would need some kind of iterator that goes over all the bits set one by one, and then you could perform a switch inside. In this case it does not make much sense because that would have the same effect as having all the conditionals one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is correct, and follows the classic C-style bitset using enums. As an alternative, you can declare the enum members using a left shift, which might improve readability for people unfamiliar:

```
enum Flags {
  flag0 = 1<<0,
  flag1 = 1<<1,
  flag2 = 1<<2
};
```

The reason why `flags & flag0` works in an if conditional is that the conditional only evaluates to false for an integral number if the number is 0. In a bitwise AND operation, where one of the operands is a power-of-2, this means that the particular bit is not set in the other operand.

An alternative is to declare your enum with implicit values:

```
enum class MyFlags {
  flag0, flag1, flag2 // implicit values are consecutive, starting with 0
};
```

And then using `std::bitset` either directly, or through a new type:

```
class MyBitset {
public:
   explicit MyBitset(std::initializer_list<MyFlags> flags) {
     for (MyFlags f : flags)
       values.set(static_cast<unsigned>(f));
   }
   
   bool test(MyFlags f) { return values.test(static_cast<unsigned>(f); }
private:
   std::bitset<WIDTH> values; // see below
};
```

The advantage is that now you can construct a set of flags with a initializer list, which a STL-like:

```
MyBitset({MyFlags::flag0, MyFlags::flag2})
```

The problem with this alternative is the maximum value. Ideally we would set the bitset width so that it has enough capacity for the most biggest flag value. We could have a type trait to specify that, and then `MyBitset` could be generic:

```
template <class T> struct MyLimits;

template <> struct MyLimits<MyFlags> {
   static constexpr bool isEnum = true;
   static constexpr size_t min = static_cast<size_t>(Flags::flag0);
   static constexpr size_t max = static_cast<size_t>(Flags::flag2);
};

// fails if MyLimits was not specialized for MyFlags
std::bitset<MyLimits<MyFlags>::max> values;
```