# Reading a 4 bit data

Tags: c, microcontroller

Hi extremely new to pic programming, or even programming in general. I am using pic18f4520 microcontroller. I want to write a code so that if `PORTD` bit 0 is high, I read the 4 bit binary data in `PORTC` bit 0-3. But I am unsure how to perform the 'read' part. Below is my code but unsure how to proceed

```c
#include<xc.h>

Void main() {

TRISD=0b111111111 // Port D bit 0 is input

TRISC=0b11111111 //RA3-RA0 i

while(1)
 
  {
       If(PORTD.bitsRD0==1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523724/c-c-check-if-one-bit-is-set-in-i-e-int-variable)

Comment: `even programming in general. I am using pic18f4520` If so, consider moving to STM32 or to one of Arduino boards, even to ESP32. Your journey into programming will be way more pleasant, and you will learn relevant microcontroller and widely-used compiler, and stm32f103 has way more power and costs the same. PIC18 is old, with very bad compiler support - the free version of XC8 is just horrible. Move to gcc and to newer boards, and if starting with microcontrollers - move to Arduino.

Comment: I second @KamilCuk's recommendation, but if you really want to learn, never ever download or use an Arduino library or its Franken-language.  Get a cheap USB programmer (e.g Dragon and some 328P chips, a breadboard, and gcc compiler.  You''ll learn more and faster than tinkering with bloated and crappy prebuilt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> I read the 4 bit binary data in PORTC bit 0-3. But I am unsure how to perform the 'read' part

Just mask the bits you are interested in. If the bits `0-3` are counted from LSB, then:

```
unsigned val = PORTC & ~0xf:
```

Then `~0xf` is all onces except the 4 bits, `&` is binary AND, so it zeros all bits except the 4 interested bits.

Comment: In fact, this zeros out the four interesting ones. Try `PORTC & 0xf` instead. Or, if you would like to read the bits one by one, `PORTC & 0x01`, `PORTC & 0x02`, `PORTC & 0x04`, and `PORTC & 0x08`.

Comment: How do u put it in code though, what type of variable can be a 4bit binary data

Comment: There is no specific 4-bit type. But any type with at least four bits will do. For example `unsigned char` (typically) have 8 bits. If you're new to this, make sure that you read up on binary and hexadecimal numbers, as well as bitwise operators like `&` and `|`, that will clear up a lot of questions.