# Fastest way to find the value of a specific bit in a number in C++

Tags: c++, integer, bit

I'm trying to write a program where I use the last 25 bits of a 32-bit integer to represent a 5x5 bingo board. I'm going to be looking at specific places a *lot*. What's the most time-efficient way to find the value of a given bit?

My guess is either:

```
int findBit (int a, int place){
    return a & (1 << place);
}
```

or

```
int findBit (int a, int place){
    return a / (1 << place) % 2;
}
```

or perhaps there is some built-in function that C++ has?

Comment: See also [C/C++ check if one bit is set in, i.e. int variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/523724/555045). Your first guess is one of the generally accepted ways. The second one, I recommend not using it..

Comment: Most time efficient way is not to use bits to represent bingo board.

Comment: Probably, the fastest way would be to not use bitfield at all, using array of 25 `int`s instead. But I doubt reading bitfield is going to be your bottleneck. Even slowest computer should be able to do millions (if not billions) of such operations per second.

Comment: if place is const then `template<int place> int findBit (int a){
    return a & (1 << place);
}`

Comment: @QuentinUK How does that make things faster? You still have to calculate the whole thing, exactly the same as in the non-template version

Comment: @Yksisarvinen findBit<10>(x) can work out that 1<<10 is 1024 beforehand.

Comment: 1 Write readable code. 2 Make it work. 3 Optimize if necessary. - it does not matter how fast incorrect program is.

Comment: Addendum to above: You're usually not being paid for fast*est*, only fast *enough*. And fast enough is generally a lot easier to find and reach.

Comment: @QuentinUK I guess it may, you're right. Don't think it's really possible to use the template here, but compiler indeed optimizes it: https://godbolt.org/z/oe1PGaqj5

Comment: what about `return (a >> place) & 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations are prolific and efficient.

I crafted a test file using bitwise (the - below) and your modular division method (+ below). The difference in assembly is shown in a diff below:

```
-   and w8, w8, w9
+   sdiv    w8, w8, w9
+   mov w10, #2
+   sdiv    w9, w8, w10
+   mul w9, w9, w10
+   subs    w8, w8, w9
```

In the test, I performed the operations one trillion two hundred eighty billion times. Here are the times with x1 being bitwise and x2 being modular division:

```
% time ./x1 ; time ./x2
18328383850248350848
5.174u 0.031s 0:05.31 97.9% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
12690158593672146048
6.440u 0.037s 0:06.53 99.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

I ran this test many times, and found the results are similar. The bitwise is about 1 1/2 second faster.

Do you need to worry about the performance of this operation on modern computers?
No.

Hasty Benchmark - not scientific

```
int main() {
    int a = INT_MAX/16, i;
    unsigned long b;
    for (; a > 0; a--) {
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            b += a & (1 << i);
        }
    }
    printf("%lu\n", b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that a good optimizer will substitute `a / (1 << place) % 2` with `(a >> place) & 1`, but if not, the cost of a division and a modulo are terrible. The latter relation should be as efficient as `a & (1 << place)`.

You can possibly do even better by directly passing the value `1 << place` instead of `place`, assuming that the calling function can work with it. Anyway it is likely that such a nano optimization would have no measurable effect.